# VHDL - updating an integer value for error check

Tags: vhdl

I've started to try to get my test benches to do some error checking for me. In the below model I use a process to check that two values are equal and if so change a boolean expression to true. 
The problem being that it does not change at all. The integer value it checks against seems to not update in the simulation, but I added a multiplexer to the architecture model to double check and it seems to respond to the change in integer value of HOW_MANY. Model and simulation below

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY rt IS
PORT (oranges, apples   :   IN  std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
        number              :   IN integer;
        pears                   :   OUT std_logic);
END ENTITY rt;

ARCHITECTURE struct OF rt IS
SIGNAL HOW_MANY : integer;
BEGIN
HOW_MANY <= to_integer(unsigned(apples) + unsigned(oranges));
pears <= '1' WHEN how_many = 2 ELSE
            '0';
END ARCHITECTURE struct;

LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY test IS
END ENTITY test;

ARCHITECTURE io OF test IS
SIGNAL oranges, apples      :   std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL number                  :     integer;
SIGNAL pears                  :   std_logic;
SIGNAL ERROR                  :   boolean := FALSE;
SIGNAL HOW_MANY            :   integer;
SIGNAL int_oranges        :   natural;
BEGIN
H1 : ENTITY work.rt(struct)
      PORT MAP (oranges, apples, number, pears);

oranges <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(int_oranges,4));
TESTER : PROCESS IS
BEGIN
    int_oranges <= 3;
    apples <= "0001";
    number <= 4;
        WAIT FOR 1 ns;
    int_oranges <= 7;
    apples <= "0001";
    number <= 4;
        WAIT FOR 1 ns;
    int_oranges <= 1;
    apples <= "0001";
    number <= 2;
        WAIT FOR 1 ns;
END PROCESS TESTER;

E_C : PROCESS (apples, int_oranges, number) IS
BEGIN
    ERROR <= number = HOW_MANY;
END PROCESS E_C;
END ARCHITECTURE io;
```

simulation

[image]

You can see that the HOW_MANY integer never changes value along with the Boolean value, but the value std_logic value for pears does change.

Cheers
D

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass `how_many` out of architecture struct of entity rt.

The signal `how_many` in architecture io of entity test is not assigned and it does not have an initial value provided.

This means for a scalar type the default initial value with be T'LEFT or -2147483648 as seen on your waveform displaying the value of test/HOW_MANY.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply do I need to add the following statement into the io architecture then?   HOW_MANY <= to_integer(unsigned(apples) + unsigned(oranges));

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to convey it from the instantiated rt?

Answer (score 2):

@User1155120 has answered the specifics.

A little more background : VHDL is a higher level language than is often assumed in that, not only is it strongly typed, but it provides very good facilities for abstraction and encapsulation, in the form of packages and entities.

Specifically, here, the "entity" is the public interface of `rt` while the architecture is private : nothing else can examine the internals. In "C" terms it is as if its `HOW_MANY` signal was declared `static`. The `HOW_MANY` signal declared in the testbench is an entirely separate signal with no connection to `rt.HOW_MANY`. And note that the qualified name `rt.HOW_MANY` is not accessible from the top level - that would break the abstraction.

So what does that imply for the testbench?

Traditionally, testing has been on the "black box" basis for each entity : set up its input ports, examine its output ports, i.e. test the heck out of its public interface, which is all you need to do to verify that it meets its specification. (And assemble larger designs out of unit-tested components).

Prior to VHDL-2008 there has been no ability to break the abstraction - and observe the internal details (which may vary between different architectures for the same entity) although you can examine all the internal signals in the simulator's waveform output.

VHDL-2008 introduces syntax to allow testbenches to break the abstraction and allow internal signals to be directly accessed via "external names" ... see this [introduction from Doulos](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_ease/#hierarchicalnames) and this [StackExchange Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125710/how-to-bring-out-internal-signals-of-a-lower-module-to-a-top-module-in-vhdl).

It should be obvious that this is fragile : change some internal detail in the architecture and you will generally have to rewrite the testbench to match.

I haven't found a good use for it yet...

Whether or not your simulator supports VHDL-2008 external names is another matter : it may be a matter of turning on VHDL-2008 compilation, or you may have to contact the tool vendor with an enhancement request to add the feature (or find a better tool).